# Include id from drop down selector with eloquent laravel and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, forms

I am pushing the 'name' instead of the 'id' value to my database. I need the correct eloquent call in order to display the specialty->id in my database rather than the name of the specialty itself. In this code, I am attempting to get the id in the $talents variable and use it as a value. However, when I attempt this, the selector does not let me choose more than one option. I THINK I NEED MULTIPLE VARIABLES FOR THIS, JUST NOT SURE HOW?

My view:

```
     <div class="container">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <strong>Select Specialty:</strong>

    <select id="multiple-checkboxes2" multiple="multiple" name="specialties" value="specialties_id">
     @if($specialties)
         @foreach($specialties as $specialty)
            <option value= "{{ $talents }}">{{$specialty->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    </div>

</select>



  {!! Form::close() !!}

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#multiple-checkboxes2').multiselect();
 });
```

Client Store Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
//
Client::create([

    'specialties' => $request->specialties,


 ] );


     return redirect('/accounts');
 }
```

display controller

```
  public function display($id)
    {




     *experimental*
            $specialties=Specialty::select('id', 'name')->orderBy('id', 
     'asc')->get();

      $talents=Specialty::select('id')->where('name', $specialties)->get();
*/experimental




        return view('accounts/display', compact('accounts', 'specialties', )->withAccount($accounts);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the values of $talent?

Comment: At first glance looks like you forgot quotes `value= {{ $talent }}` should be `value="{{ $talent }}"`

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez Talent is defined in the display controller, it is my attempt at getting the id from the specialty to appear in the db, instead of the "name". So I take am trying to take the $id of the $specialty-name that is selected, but when I do include $talents, the selector in the view won't allow me to select multiples